# Regex - Find first # of characters before a specific character (like Excel's LEFT function)

Tags: replace, backreference

I'm trying to find a way to find/replace email addresses in a .csv file (single column) with the first 10 characters before the `@` symbol.  An example CSV file would be:

```
PrimarySmtpAddress
userA@domain.com
UserB@domain.com
UserAlongername@domain.com
UserBlongername@domain.com
```

My desired output would be:

```
PrimarySmtpAddress
UserA
UserB
UserAlonge
UserBlonge
```

I so far have found how to just get rid of the `@` and everything that follows by doing:

find:     `(.*)@.*`
replace:     `\1`

I'm hoping I can add something after the     `\1` that specifies to only replace with first 10 characters of what is contained in     `\1`.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Try making your regex `(.{1,10})@.*` and replacing with `\1`. The `{1,10}` means "one to ten" of `.`.

Depending on the tool you are using to do the replacement, it might try to match the entire string - in that case you could use `^.*?(.{1,10})@.*$`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer.  Using Notepad++ with Regular expression selected, neither of those would find any of my email addresses unfortunately.  Maybe Notepad++ is to blame?

Comment: Oh. Regex in Notepad++ is the one thing I don't like about it - it sucks. There's no `{n,m}` operator there and hence no way to do what you want (with regex anyway). [Notepad++ regex reference](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions).